# User Defined Function Compilation Failed When Using .apply() in CUDF

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, apply, cudf

Was trying to use a function on a cudf to create values for a new column in the data frame using .apply()

```
import cudf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import sys

sys.version
> '3.9.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:45:29) \n[GCC 10.4.0]'

gdf = cudf.read_csv('datav3.csv')

def Rival(row):

     if row['event_name'] == 'HOU21':
          return 1

     if row['event_name'] == 'TEN21':
          return 1

     if row['event_name'] == 'JAX21':
          return 1

     if row['event_name'] == 'HOU22':
          return 1

     if row['event_name'] == 'TEN22':
          return 1

     if row['event_name'] == 'JAX22':
          return 1

     else:
          return 0


gdf['rival'] = gdf.apply(lambda row: Rival(row), axis = 1)
```

Here is the error that python is outputting. This is a trusted notebook. This function worked fine on a pandas dataframe, but is now having issues with cudf and I'm not entirely sure why. The rapidsai version I am using is rapids 22.12

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:2014, in IndexedFrame._apply(self, func, kernel_getter, *args, **kwargs)
> 2013 try:
> 2014     kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
> 2015         self, func, args, kernel_getter=kernel_getter
> 2016     )
> 2017 except Exception as e:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
> 78 with self._recreate_cm():
> 79     return func(*args, **kwds)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py:222, in _compile_or_get(frame, func, args, kernel_getter)
> 219 # precompile the user udf to get the right return type.
> 220 # could be a MaskedType or a scalar type.
> 222 kernel, scalar_return_type = kernel_getter(frame, func, args)
> 223 np_return_type = (
> 224     numpy_support.as_dtype(scalar_return_type)
> 225     if scalar_return_type.is_internal
> 226     else scalar_return_type.np_dtype
> 227 )
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/row_function.py:133, in _get_row_kernel(frame, func, args)
> 130 row_type = _get_frame_row_type(
> 131     np.dtype(list(_all_dtypes_from_frame(frame).items()))
> 132 )
> 133 scalar_return_type = _get_udf_return_type(row_type, func, args)
> 134 # this is the signature for the final full kernel compilation
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
> 78 with self._recreate_cm():
> 79     return func(*args, **kwds)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py:61, in _get_udf_return_type(argty, func, args)
> 59 # Get the return type. The PTX is also returned by compile_udf, but is not
> 60 # needed here.
> 61 ptx, output_type = cudautils.compile_udf(func, compile_sig)
> 63 if not isinstance(output_type, MaskedType):
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/utils/cudautils.py:250, in compile_udf(udf, type_signature)
> 248 # We haven't compiled a function like this before, so need to fall back to
> 249 # compilation with Numba
> 250 ptx_code, return_type = cuda.compile_ptx_for_current_device(
> 251     udf, type_signature, device=True
> 252 )
> 253 if not isinstance(return_type, cudf.core.udf.masked_typing.MaskedType):
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:293, in compile_ptx_for_current_device(pyfunc, args, debug, lineinfo, device, fastmath, opt)
> 292 cc = get_current_device().compute_capability
> 293 return compile_ptx(pyfunc, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
> 294                    device=device, fastmath=fastmath, cc=cc, opt=True)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
> 34 with self:
> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:269, in compile_ptx(pyfunc, args, debug, lineinfo, device, fastmath, cc, opt)
> 262 nvvm_options = {
> 263     'debug': debug,
> 264     'lineinfo': lineinfo,
> 265     'fastmath': fastmath,
> 266     'opt': 3 if opt else 0
> 267 }
> 269 cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, None, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
> 270                     fastmath=fastmath,
> 271                     nvvm_options=nvvm_options)
> 272 resty = cres.signature.return_type
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
> 34 with self:
> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:212, in compile_cuda(pyfunc, return_type, args, debug, lineinfo, inline, fastmath, nvvm_options)
> 211 with target_override('cuda'):
> 212     cres = compiler.compile_extra(typingctx=typingctx,
> 213                                   targetctx=targetctx,
> 214                                   func=pyfunc,
> 215                                   args=args,
> 216                                   return_type=return_type,
> 217                                   flags=flags,
> 218                                   locals={},
> 219                                   pipeline_class=CUDACompiler)
> 221 library = cres.library
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:716, in compile_extra(typingctx, targetctx, func, args, return_type, flags, locals, library, pipeline_class)
> 714 pipeline = pipeline_class(typingctx, targetctx, library,
> 715                           args, return_type, flags, locals)
> 716 return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:452, in CompilerBase.compile_extra(self, func)
> 451 self.state.lifted_from = None
> 452 return self._compile_bytecode()
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:520, in CompilerBase._compile_bytecode(self)
> 519 assert self.state.func_ir is None
> 520 return self._compile_core()
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:499, in CompilerBase._compile_core(self)
> 498         if is_final_pipeline:
> 499             raise e
> 500 else:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:486, in CompilerBase._compile_core(self)
> 485 try:
> 486     pm.run(self.state)
> 487     if self.state.cr is not None:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:368, in PassManager.run(self, state)
> 367 patched_exception = self._patch_error(msg, e)
> 368 raise patched_exception
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:356, in PassManager.run(self, state)
> 355 if isinstance(pass_inst, CompilerPass):
> 356     self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
> 357 else:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
> 34 with self:
> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:311, in PassManager._runPass(self, index, pss, internal_state)
> 310 with SimpleTimer() as pass_time:
> 311     mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
> 312 with SimpleTimer() as finalize_time:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:273, in PassManager._runPass.<locals>.check(func, compiler_state)
> 272 def check(func, compiler_state):
> 273     mangled = func(compiler_state)
> 274     if mangled not in (True, False):
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py:105, in BaseTypeInference.run_pass(self, state)
> 102 with fallback_context(state, 'Function "%s" failed type inference'
> 103                       % (state.func_id.func_name,)):
> 104     # Type inference
> 105     typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(
> 106         state.typingctx,
> 107         state.targetctx,
> 108         state.func_ir,
> 109         state.args,
> 110         state.return_type,
> 111         state.locals,
> 112         raise_errors=self._raise_errors)
> 113     state.typemap = typemap
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py:81, in type_inference_stage(typingctx, targetctx, interp, args, return_type, locals, raise_errors)
> 79     infer.seed_type(k, v)
> 81 infer.build_constraint()
> 82 # return errors in case of partial typing
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1039, in TypeInferer.build_constraint(self)
> 1038 for inst in blk.body:
> 1039     self.constrain_statement(inst)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1386, in TypeInferer.constrain_statement(self, inst)
> 1385 if isinstance(inst, ir.Assign):
> 1386     self.typeof_assign(inst)
> 1387 elif isinstance(inst, ir.SetItem):
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1459, in TypeInferer.typeof_assign(self, inst)
> 1458 elif isinstance(value, (ir.Global, ir.FreeVar)):
> 1459     self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
> 1460 elif isinstance(value, ir.Arg):
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1559, in TypeInferer.typeof_global(self, inst, target, gvar)
> 1558 try:
> 1559     typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
> 1560 except TypingError as e:
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1480, in TypeInferer.resolve_value_type(self, inst, val)
> 1479     msg = str(e)
> 1480 raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
> 
> TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Untyped global name 'Rival': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
> 
> File "<timed exec>", line 1:
> <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
> 
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> File <timed exec>:1
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
> 76 @wraps(func)
> 77 def inner(*args, **kwds):
> 78     with self._recreate_cm():
> 79         return func(*args, **kwds)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/dataframe.py:4369, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
> 4366 if result_type is not None:
> 4367     raise ValueError("The `result_type` kwarg is not yet supported.")
> 4369 return self._apply(func, _get_row_kernel, *args, **kwargs)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
> 76 @wraps(func)
> 77 def inner(*args, **kwds):
> 78     with self._recreate_cm():
> 79         return func(*args, **kwds)
> 
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/rapids-22.12/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:2018, in IndexedFrame._apply(self, func, kernel_getter, *args, **kwargs)
> 2014     kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
> 2015         self, func, args, kernel_getter=kernel_getter
> 2016     )
> 2017 except Exception as e:
> 2018     raise ValueError(
> 2019         "user defined function compilation failed."
> 2020     ) from e
> 2022 # Mask and data column preallocated
> 2023 ans_col = _return_arr_from_dtype(retty, len(self))
> 
> ValueError: user defined function compilation failed.
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a better way to do this in RAPIDS cuDF that leverages with the parallel capabilities of your GPU, and can also be done in the Pandas API, using `.loc`.  As I don't have direct access to you data source, I'm going to use the NBA dataset from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/.  For ease of understanding for others with the same question, I'm going to use a single example.  You can rinse and repeat or combine filters appropriately.  Please adjust your code accordingly.

```
import cudf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import sys

gdf = cudf.read_csv('https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/nba.csv')
print(gdf.head()) # for reference
gdf["event_name"] = 0 # Create your new Column, event_name, sets all values to 0
gdf.loc[gdf["Team"]== "Atlanta Hawks", "event_name"] = 1 # sets event_name to 1 at every instance where Team == Atlanta Hawks
print(gdf.loc[gdf["Team"] != "Atlanta Hawks"]) # see that event_name == 0 for those teams
print(gdf.loc[gdf["Team"] == "Atlanta Hawks"]) # see that event_name == 1 for the Hawks
```

You can change the library to Pandas and see that it will work there too.  Even in Pandas, applys are great when there are no APIs that accomplishes the desired task.  However, using the API is always the fastest and best way! :) .  There are other ways to skin this cat, but this is the one i have for you today.